# Is $\Bbb Z_p[x] / z_p(x)$ Field if $z_p(x)$ is Irreducible Over $\Bbb Z_p[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have $F_1 = \Bbb Z_3[x]/(x^3 +x^2 +2)$ and $F_2 = \Bbb Z_3[x]/(x^3 +x^2+2)$

If $x^3 +x^2 +2$ and $x^3 +x^2+2$ are irreducible over $\Bbb Z_3[x]$, are they field? If so, why?

also, more generally, Is $\Bbb Z_p[x] / z_p(x)$ field if $z_p(x)$ is irreducible Over $\Bbb Z_p[x]$?

Comment: $F_1 = \Bbb Z_3[x]/(x^3 +x^2 +2)$ and $F_2 = \Bbb Z_3[x]/(x^3 +x^2+2)$? Did you mean to have the polynomials be different?

Comment: Yeah, in an PID, every nonzero prime ideal is maximal. A prime ideal generated by a prime element, and in PID, prime element = irreducible element

Answer (score 3):

The general facts are:

- If $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $R/I$ is a field iff $I$ is maximal.
- If $D$ is a PID and $a \in D$, then $(a)$ is a maximal ideal iff $a$ is irreducible.
- If $F$ is a field, then $F[X]$ is a PID.

However, we can prove directly that $F[X]/(g(X))$ is a field iff $g(X)$ is irreducible.

Indeed, it follows from polynomial division with remainder that every element of $F[X]/(g(X))$ has a representative of the form $h(x)$ with $h=0$ or $\deg h < \deg g$. Since $g$ is irreducible, $h$ must be coprime with $g$ and so $1=ag+bh$. Then $bh=1$ in $F[X]/(g(X))$. Thus, every nonzero element is invertible, and $F[X]/(g(X))$ is a field.

Comment: what does PID refer to?

Comment: @Beverlie PID = principal ideal domain